How to dissolve Chromium (III) Oxide in an acid
I've been trying to dissolve Chromium (III) Oxide in an acid in order to eventually make Chromium (III) Hydroxide, but attempts from online sources that have stated this should work have failed. I've most recently tried to dissolve it in Hydrochloric Acid to get the Chromium (III) chloride and make the Hydroxide from that, but no matter what I can't get it to dissolve in anything. I've read on forums that adding Hydrogen Peroxide to the Hydrochloric acid would work, left it for a day and tried heating it up but nothing happened. I've tried Sulfuric and Nitric as well. I was trying to avoid having to make Sodium Dichromate as a precursor as stated in Fritz Ullmann's Encyclopedia, but it seems it may be required.

https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does-anyone-know-a-way-to-solve-Cr2O3

Given the reaction suggested by @NilayGhosh, "Chromium(III) oxide (Cr2O3) can be reactively dissolved with sulfuric acid (~85 wt%; H2SO4/Cr2O3 ≥ 6 wt/wt) mixed with perchloric acid (HClO4/Cr2O3 ≈ ½ wt/wt) by ~175 ºC (≤ 4h; under reflux)," it might be somewhat more economical to buy it (or to make it from chromium sulfate).

As Nilay Ghosh and Dr Moishe Pippik suggest, you need special conditions to get $\ce{Cr2O3}$ to dissolve. Usually, as with the heated sulfuric acid/perchloric acid recipe indicated in the comment, you are oxidizing the Cr(III) to Cr(VI), similar to the sodium dichromate intermediate indicated in the question.
For the record, in case the comments disappear, I requote the method:

Chromium(III) oxide ($\ce{Cr2O3}$) can be reactively dissolved with sulfuric acid (~85 wt%; $\ce{H2SO4/Cr2O3}$ ≥ 6 wt/wt) mixed with perchloric acid ($\ce{HClO4/Cr2O3}$ ≈ ½ wt/wt) by ~175 ºC (≤ 4h; under reflux)

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does-anyone-know-a-way-to-solve-Cr2O3
If you must avoid Cr(VI), I see two options:

Use hydrofluoric acid, which is generally good for attacking oxides of hard-acid cations. It's used to pickle stainless steels which have $\ce{Cr2O3}$ in their scale, and Wikipedia hints that $\ce{Cr2O3}$ can be reacted with hydrofluoric acid to make the fluoride salt. But... hydrofluoric acid is very dangerous to work with. Also the fluoride is not freely soluble in water, making further reaction to form the hydroxide still difficult.

Buy a more soluble chtomium(III) salt such as the chloride or the sulfate.



Thanks I completely forgot about this method after reading it a while ago lol. I most likely forgot it because I need to get the pechloric acid and a good reflux setup for this. If it ends up working I'll mark this as the answer.

Not sure I'd like to boil perchloric acid -- the thought gives me acid reflux. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O'Connor_Plating_Works_disaster

I have often solubilized $\ce{Cr2O3}$ by fusion in basic medium. I know it's not what Salmoncatt wants. But it works so nicely, much better than oxidation in acidic medium. It goes like this:
First mix $1$ part $\ce{KNO3}$ plus $3$ parts $\ce{Na2CO3}$. Use this mixture to make a new mixture with $1$ part $\ce{Cr2O3}$ + $8$ parts of the previous mixture $\ce{KNO3 + Na2CO3}$. Heat the final mixture in a platinum, silver or nickel crucible with a Bunsen burner. The mass becomes slowly liquid and yellow. When it is homogeneous, let it cool. Dissolve the whole mass in water. The yellow solution contains chromium as chromate ions $\ce{CrO4^{2-}}$.

Yeah that's the Chromate route that Fritz Ullmann talked about. I appreciate your details to the method because I've ultimately decided to try both.

An oxidizer, perchlorate, nitrate, peroxide converts CrIII to CrVI. This is faster in base than in acid. I found one comment that fusion with bisulfate works. I would try careful fusion of a well pulverized sample with sodium carbonate or hydroxide followed by neutralization with ammonium chloride to precipitate the hydroxide. If you decide to go the chromate route an easy way to reduce the chromate is to carefully add ethanol or isopropanol to the acidic solution [Vodka might work]. Organic chemistry has its uses.

"Vodka might work". And waste perfectly good vodka on a chemical reaction? Oy!
